# ASE 15 is getting disconnected from PB development environment(DB Profile connection) after 1 hour idle time

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I am facing an issue that, ASE 15 is getting disconnected from PB development environment(DB Profile connection) and DB Artisan tool after an idle time of one hour. Can anybody suggest how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the database connection alive by making sure there is activity after a certain amount of idle time passes.

```
//In the Open Event of a window that will be running for a long time
//Sets Idle Time
Idle(600)
```

Then add code to "IDLE" event in the Application Object.

```
int li_site

//Runs a simple query to see if we are still connected to the database
select current_site
  into :li_site
  from comp_settings;

//Not connected
if (SQLCA.SQLCode <> 0) then

  //Connects to the DB
  Connect using sqlca;

end if
```

Then don't forget to turn off the Idle timer.

```
//In the Close Event of a window
//Turns off Idle Time
Idle(0)
```

Comment: Thanks Shenn for your response. Yes, we can keep the connection active in Powerbuilder code as per your comment. But i am talking about the isql session tool in PB (DB Profile connection).

Comment: This should still be the Idle setting for the database connection.  Look in the "Advanced Options" or "Advanced" section.  There will be an option for "Idle" or "Idle Session".  Put the number zero in there to turn off the idle timeout checking.